# Can't install Guitar Pro 6 on 64-bit Ubuntu on laptop, but I could on desktop

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit on both my laptop and my desktop.

I managed to install Guitar Pro 6 on my desktop by using 32-bit dependencies, following the instructions [here](http://getsatisfaction.guitar-pro.com/arobas_music/topics/how_to_install_gp6_from_the_demo_deb_in_ubuntu_11_10_64_bits) to install:

I followed the exact same methods on my laptop, but Guitar Pro 6 won't run. 
I have tried the official demo from the website, which didn't work either.

When downgrading my libraries to 32-bit for Guitar Pro 6 install, at some point in the terminal it had an issue with LibGL, saying it was installed by the video driver.

I suspect this may be the cause of the problem, since after Googling for hours, the only issues were with libportaudio, which I downgraded successfully.

So, is there a way to downgrade LibGL to 32-bit, since it is installed with the video driver? Would this stop my display working, or is it impossible?

--

I also tried installing the Windows version under Wine and PlayOnLinux, neither of which worked. Guitar Pro 6 installs successfully, but then nothing happens when I try to run it.

If I am wrong about LibGL, does anyone know a way I could get Guitar Pro 6 working? I desperately need it to work, and don't want to downgrade to 32-bit.

**UPDATE: I ran /opt/GuitarPro6 !$ ldd ./GuitarPro and it reported that libGL.so.1 was 'not found'
I found the file(s) in the nvidia-current directory, and placed them in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/
The issue now is, how can I tell Guitar Pro 6 where to find them?**

Comment: Did you install Guitar Hero using wine?As you mentioned you downloaded the 32 bit libraries but you said that you are using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Comment: *Guitar Pro

I converted a .tgz to a .deb and installed that, as in the instructions from the link in my post

I did try with Wine, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install the `libglu1-mesa:i386` package. You cannot *downgrade* the GL library only as used by the system to 32-bit, but you can have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions installed on a 64-bit Ubuntu PC.

Answer (score 0):

Please *DO NOT MESS WITH SYSTEM FILES DIRECTLY* as long as you are not completely sure what you are doing.

You do not 'downgraded' the packages - at least I hope so - you should just install the 32-bit libraries too.

In case there's a system message like "openGL installed by driver": Note it!

If you have proprietary nVidia drivers installed, they ship their own openGL implementation. Install those alongside their 32-bit libraries. Install mesa 32-bit.
This should work.

EDIT:
And revert all those changes with copying some librarirs from one place to another! There's a reason to that why they are there.
If you do not exactly knoe what you are doing, you probably do not know enough to "fix" the system - the problem is not that Ubuntu is (was) broken but that you just did not install all dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

Just create a symlink to the file whose name starts with `libgl`, inside the directory where Guitar Pro was installed.

Comment: I've reworded this a bit for clarity, but I recommend expanding this to explain exactly how to find that file, and exactly how to make the symbolic link.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest you to install tuxguitar instead It can read Guitar Pro tabs.

```
sudo apt-get install tuxguitar
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, but it is possibly useful, so please post it as a comment instead.